# Latex Miktex packages

Tags: latex, miktex

Any idea how I can install packages (ctable) to my Miktex portable when I dont have internet access on the machine with miktex?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the nature of the package. Obviously you need to download the files first. If you have them, this [page](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/systems/tex/new-packages.html) will tell you what to do next.